# Problema al instalar un proyecto django con virtualenv en debian

Tags: python, django, linux, debian

tengo un problema, ya instalé el entorno virtual y ya instale con pip django, solo que hay un problema al crear la estructua del proyecto, me aparece lo siguiente:

```
(venv)padawan@debian:~/Documents/Git/landing-page$ django-admin startproject clinkcapital .
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/padawan/Documents/Git/landing-page/venv/bin/django-admin", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
  File "/home/padawan/Documents/Git/landing-page/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/padawan/Documents/Git/landing-page/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 316, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/padawan/Documents/Git/landing-page/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/padawan/Documents/Git/landing-page/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/padawan/Documents/Git/landing-page/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 97, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/home/padawan/Documents/Git/landing-page/venv/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2212, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2212, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'cashflow'
```

De donde **No module named 'cashflow'** hace referencia a otro proyecto con ese mismo nombre. No sé si habré movido algo al virtualenv o qué habrá pasado.
O no sé si tal vez de donde lo está jalando y por qué pasa eso si el otro proyecto lo tengo en un entorno virtual... quizá en una de esas desventuras lo haya instalado sin un entorno virtual, no sé.

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Ahí dice que en `INSTALLED_APPS`... revísalo. Verifica también la variable de entorno `DJANGO_SETTINGS` o algo así.

Comment: Muchas gracias efectivamente era la variable de entorno DJANGO_SETTINGS la tenia configurada para un proyecto, pero se me pasó de largo, o que hice fue instalar virtualenvwrapper para que tener varios entornos con diferentes configuraciones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema venía de variable de entorno DJANGO_SETTINGS que tenía definida en ~/.bashrc , la tenia configurada para otro proyecto, pero se me había olvidado esa configuración.

La solución fue fue instalar virtualenvwrapper para tener varios entornos con diferentes configuraciones de una manera muy sencilla.